# XPages xsp.session.transient when set to true hierarchical tabbed navigation stops working

Tags: xpages

I am basically trying to understand xsp properties for XPages. I have referred multiple websites and found a small problem to understand the **xsp.session.transient** property.

This Blog( http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/17.07.2011101855KLEBRW.htm?opendocument&comments) states that:

"this flag means that unique session objects will be created per request to the server and discarded right after the request ended"

When I look into this blog (http://www.itwu-demo.net/web/itwublog.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=E42CD391498BDE9CC1257A770040B2EB) it says that setting it to true may result in loss of objects. I observed this side effect when I used tabbed navigation on my page. The code mentioned below would just refresh for the second hierarchical tab and would never go to the third hierarchy. If I set the property to false it works well. However, I would like to understand the reason of this behavior? Also, how exactly the property could be used for our benefit? Can anyone please throw some light here. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1">
        <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab" id="tabPanel1">a</xp:tabPanel>
        <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab2" id="tabPanel2">b<xp:br></xp:br>
            <xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel2">
                <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab" id="tabPanel3">c</xp:tabPanel>
                <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab2" id="tabPanel4">d<xp:br></xp:br>
                    <xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel3">
                        <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab" id="tabPanel5">e</xp:tabPanel>
                        <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab2" id="tabPanel6">f</xp:tabPanel>
                    </xp:tabbedPanel>
                </xp:tabPanel>
            </xp:tabbedPanel>
        </xp:tabPanel>
    </xp:tabbedPanel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsp.session.transient` property is documented in the [XPages Portable Command Guide book](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/ibmpressisbn/9780132943055?Open).

The following is a summary of the property taken from the book:

*By default, the XPages runtime is a stateful web application framework. A request for an XPage results in a degree of server-side processing that begins with creation or retrieval of a user session and ultimately ends with a rendering process that builds up the content for a response. During this server-side processing, a user session configuration object, along with all the controls on a requested XPage, have their respective properties and values serialized to disk and/or deserialized from disk. This is due to the inbuilt serialization mechanism of XPages that manages and provides the stateful characteristics of the XPages runtime. Based on application requirements, it might be beneficial from a performance and scalability perspective for an application not to participate in this serialization process, to optimize its level of participation. This aim of the `xsp.session.transient` property is to provide a way to control how user session objects are serialized between requests.*

*By default, the XPages runtime sets this property to `false`. Therefore, the serialization process includes all user session objects, but not the sessionScope object. This means that any XPages a given user requests are serialized/deserialized in association with the user session object over the life of that user session object. They are discarded along with the user session object when the overall user session timeout duration passes.*

*Alternatively, if this property is set to `true`, the XPages runtime automatically avoids serializing user session objects between XPage requests. It is important to note that
a user session object still is instantiated for a request, but it simply is not serialized between requests. This also means that properties and values of controls within requested XPages still participate in the serialization process—this ensures that an XPage can still provide a rich user experience for the scoped variables and partial execution of actions, for example. However, when a user navigates to another XPage, the associated stateful data for that XPage is discarded because the user session object is not serialized between requests. This feature is made available for use cases that require an extremely optimal level of performance tuning where server memory must be finely managed. Note that such use cases are those in which partial updates are applied against only the current page; full page refreshes cause the state to be discarded between requests. Therefore, the design and intent of the page require careful consideration to benefit from this feature.*

---

As you read from the documentation, the state of objects are not kept between requests if `xsp.session.transient` is set to `true`.

I can highly recommend buying the XPages Portable Command Guide.

Comment: Thanks for the description. So, firstly, I understand you meant "true" in your second last paragraph?right? Also, if I understand it correctly then tabbed navigation performs a full refresh on the page and hence the object is not stored between multiple requests?right? In such case I would like to know why is tabbed navigation performing full refresh when it could be accomplished by partial refresh?(Since, in this case it would work even when I set the property true).

Comment: False changed to True :-) Thanks

Comment: No problem. :)..Also, would be good to hear from you about the second part of my comment..!

Comment: Setting transient to true means that objects are not kept between *requests* - which means it affects partial refreshes too (as I understand it)

Comment: The reason I asked you was because in the description you provide in the third last paragraph it suggests that: "this ensures that an XPage can still provide a rich user experience for the scoped variables and partial execution of actions, for example.". Anyways, I conclude that if we set the property to true in either case(partial or full refresh) it breaks down since the state is not stored. Thanks for your valuable comments :)